# Create factory with using microsoft DI

Tags: c#, .net

I have hierarchy classes and generic classes of http reauest, response:

```
        public abstract class Publication
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Producer { get; set; }
        }


        public class Book : Publication
        {
            public string Topic { get; set; }
            public string Autor { get; set; }
        }

        public class CopyBook : Publication
        {
            public string Topic { get; set; }
            public int CountPages { get; set; }
        }

        public class NoteBook : Publication
        {
            public int Cost { get; set; }
        }


        public class Request<T> where T : Publication
        {
            public Guid RequestId { get; }
            public T Publication { get; }

            public Request(T publication)
            {
                RequestId = Guid.NewGuid();
                Publication = publication;
            }
        }

        public class Response<T> where T : Publication
        {
            private Guid ResponseId { get; set; }
            public T Publication { get; set; }
        }
```

I use Http API client with Refit library. For it I create interface:

```
        public interface IPublicationApiClinet<T> where T : Publication
        {
            bool Send(Request<T> publication);
            Response<T> UpdatingRecv(Request<T> publication);
        }
```

The refit library create implementation for the interface automatically. The refit library not injecting client with base class IFormApiClinet only child classes - for example IFormApiClinet.

I want to create factory to creation clients depend on type publication. I created her:

```
        public interface IClientFactory
        {
            IPublicationApiClient<Publication> Create(Publication publication);
        }

        public class ClientFactory : IClientFactory
        {
            private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
            public ClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            }

            public IPublicationApiClient<Publication> Create(Publication publication)
            {
                switch (publication)
                {
                    case Book _:
                        return _serviceProvider.GetService<IPublicationApiClient<Book>>();
                    case NoteBook _:
                        return _serviceProvider.GetService<IPublicationApiClient<NoteBook>>();
                    case CopyBook _:
                        return _serviceProvider.GetService<IPublicationApiClient<CopyBook>>();
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }
        }
```

The factory does not compile because IPublicationApiClient with child class don't cast to base class for returning. For example `IPublicationApiClient<Book>` to `IPublicationApiClient<Publication>`. How fix it?

I will use the factory in service, which getting publications of different types (Book, CopyBook, NoteBook) from DB.

```
        public interface IPublicationSerice
        {
            void Proccess(string name);
        }

         public class PublicationSerice : IPublicationSerice 
         {
            private readonly IClientFactory _clientFactory;
            public PublicationSerice(IClientFactory clientFactory)
            {
                _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            }

            public void Proccess(string name)
            {
                Publication book = new Book();
                //It is analog:
                //var specification = new PublicationByNameSpecification<Publication>(name);
                //var publication = await _publicationRepository.GetAsync(specification);

                var bookClient = _clientFactory.Create(book);
                bookClient.Send(new Request<Publication>(book));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Even if you declared `IPublicationApiClient` to be contravariant `<out T>`, `Request<T>` and `Response<T>` can't be declared with a contravariant `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making the `ClientFactory` method generic as well:

```
public interface IClientFactory
{
    IPublicationApiClient<T> Create<T>(T publication) where T : Publication;
}

public class ClientFactory : IClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IPublicationApiClient<T> Create<T>(T publication) where T : Publication
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService<IPublicationApiClient<T>>()
            ?? throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

---

Here's a simple example of that working:

```
public class PublicationApiClient<T> : IPublicationApiClient<T> where T : Publication
{
    public bool Send(Request<T> publication)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello from {typeof(T).Name} client!");
        return true;
    }

    public Response<T> UpdatingRecv(Request<T> publication)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IClientFactory, ClientFactory>()
        .AddSingleton(typeof(IPublicationApiClient<>), typeof(PublicationApiClient<>))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    IClientFactory factory = provider.GetService<IClientFactory>();

    Book book = new Book();
    IPublicationApiClient<Book> bookClient = factory.Create(book);
    bookClient.Send(new Request<Book>(book));

    NoteBook notebook = new NoteBook();
    IPublicationApiClient<NoteBook> notebookClient = factory.Create(notebook);
    notebookClient.Send(new Request<NoteBook>(notebook));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, @devNull . My service work with base class - Publication. In this class object different child types (Book, NoteBook, CopyBook) are readed. The factory don't work with base class: ```var client = factory.Create(publication);``` . How to make it work?

Comment: @ivanof81 The `Publication` class is abstract, so how would you do that? Maybe update your question with more details of how you expect it to work in that case, and I could try to update my answer accordingly

Comment: Ok. @devNull , I have updated the question - using case has been added.